# How can I attach a patch.diff-file from sourceforge.net?

Tags: patch, pyopengl

I found a patch that will fix a bug in my PyOpenGL-program 
[here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyopengl/bugs/259/).

But I have no idea how I can install this patch in arch-linux.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has nothing to do with python or openGL, so you might want to remove those tags.

You are looking for the `patch`-utility and then, in the directory that contains the `src`-folder, do something like
`patch -p0 -b < patch-py33-import.diff`

The -b switch creates backup files before patching, the -p switch tells patch to use the complete path/filename that are given in the patch file.

Comment: The patch tool I can find in /usr/bin, but there aren't any source-files, only the compiled versions. I'll remove the pre-compiled package and try to use the source-code-version from Sourceforge.net. Thank you !

Comment: Why are you looking for the source code of `patch`? Please don't remove anything unless you are really sure what you're doing!

Comment: No ! Not for the patch tool, for the PyOpenGL-package. Sorry, it's because my bad english-knowledge.

Comment: I give it up ! No PyOpenGL, no 3D-Graphics. I cannot find the sources for PyOpenGL and PyOpenGL_accelerate. No source-code, no patch.